# Changing emacs theme modeline colors

Tags: themes, mode-line

I've installed this great theme `atom-one-dark` and I love it.

However, one thing I'd like to change is the modeline colors.

Currently, the *grey* one is the **inactive** one and the *black* one is the **active** one:

[image]

I'd like to change it to:

*grey (filled)* = **active**

*grey (border-only)* = **inactive**

But I have no Idea how to go about it and the theme file has a lot of lisp code. I'd appreciate if someone could at least point me in the right direction in terms of what I would have to change in the theme file.

Here are the contents of `atom-one-dark-theme.el`:

```
    ;;; atom-one-dark-theme.el --- Atom One Dark color theme
;;
;; Copyright 2016 Jonathan Chu
;;
;; Author: Jonathan Chu <me@jonathanchu.is>
;; URL: https://github.com/jonathanchu/atom-one-dark-theme
;; Package-Version: 20161101.1955
;; Version: 0.4.0
;;
;;; Commentary:
;;
;; An Emacs port of the Atom One Dark theme from Atom.io.
;;
;;; Code:

(deftheme atom-one-dark
  "Atom One Dark - An Emacs port of the Atom One Dark theme from Atom.io.")

(defvar atom-one-dark-colors-alist
  '(("atom-one-dark-accent"   . "#528BFF")
    ("atom-one-dark-fg"       . "#ABB2BF")
    ("atom-one-dark-bg"       . "#282C34")
    ("atom-one-dark-bg-1"     . "#121417")
    ("atom-one-dark-bg-hl"    . "#2F343D")
    ("atom-one-dark-gutter"   . "#666D7A")
    ("atom-one-dark-accent"   . "#AEB9F5")
    ("atom-one-dark-mono-1"   . "#ABB2BF")
    ("atom-one-dark-mono-2"   . "#828997")
    ("atom-one-dark-mono-3"   . "#5C6370")
    ("atom-one-dark-cyan"     . "#56B6C2")
    ("atom-one-dark-blue"     . "#61AFEF")
    ("atom-one-dark-purple"   . "#C678DD")
    ("atom-one-dark-green"    . "#98C379")
    ("atom-one-dark-red-1"    . "#E06C75")
    ("atom-one-dark-red-2"    . "#BE5046")
    ("atom-one-dark-orange-1" . "#D19A66")
    ("atom-one-dark-orange-2" . "#E5C07B")
    ("atom-one-dark-gray"     . "#3E4451")
    ("atom-one-dark-silver"   . "#AAAAAA")
    ("atom-one-dark-black"    . "#0F1011"))
  "List of Atom One Dark colors.")

(defmacro atom-one-dark-with-color-variables (&rest body)
  "Bind the colors list around BODY."
  (declare (indent 0))
  `(let ((class '((class color) (min-colors 89)))
         ,@ (mapcar (lambda (cons)
                      (list (intern (car cons)) (cdr cons)))
                    atom-one-dark-colors-alist))
     ,@body))

(atom-one-dark-with-color-variables
  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'atom-one-dark

   `(default ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
   `(success ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(warning ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(error ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1 :weight bold))))
   `(link ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue :underline t :weight bold))))
   `(link-visited ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue :underline t :weight normal))))
   `(cursor ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-accent))))
   `(fringe ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
   `(region ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(highlight ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(hl-line ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-hl))))
   `(vertical-border ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))
   `(secondary-selection ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1))))
   `(query-replace ((t (:inherit (isearch)))))
   `(minibuffer-prompt ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-silver))))

   `(font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))
   `(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))
   `(font-lock-comment-delimiter-face ((default (:inherit (font-lock-comment-face)))))
   `(font-lock-doc-face ((t (:inherit (font-lock-string-face)))))
   `(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue))))
   `(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(font-lock-preprocessor-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))
   `(font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(font-lock-warning-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3 :bold t))))

   ;; mode-line
   `(mode-line ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-black :foreground ,atom-one-dark-silver))))
   `(mode-line-buffer-id ((t (:weight bold))))
   `(mode-line-emphasis ((t (:weight bold))))
   `(mode-line-inactive ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))

   ;; ido
   `(ido-first-match ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple :weight bold))))
   `(ido-only-match ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1 :weight bold))))
   `(ido-subdir ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue))))
   `(ido-virtual ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))

   ;; ace-jump
   `(ace-jump-face-background ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :inverse-video nil))))
   `(ace-jump-face-foreground ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :inverse-video nil))))

   ;; company-mode
   `(company-tooltip ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1))))
   `(company-tooltip-annotation ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1))))
   `(company-tooltip-selection ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(company-tooltip-mouse ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(company-tooltip-common ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1))))
   `(company-tooltip-common-selection ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(company-preview ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
   `(company-preview-common ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
   `(company-scrollbar-fg ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-mono-1))))
   `(company-scrollbar-bg ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1))))

   ;; compilation
   `(compilation-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg))))
   `(compilation-line-number ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(compilation-column-number ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))

   ;; isearch
   `(isearch ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-bg :background ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(isearch-fail ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-2 :background nil))))
   `(lazy-highlight ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :underline ,atom-one-dark-purple))))

   ;; diff-hl (https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl)
   '(diff-hl-change ((t (:foreground "#E9C062" :background "#8b733a"))))
   '(diff-hl-delete ((t (:foreground "#CC6666" :background "#7a3d3d"))))
   '(diff-hl-insert ((t (:foreground "#A8FF60" :background "#547f30"))))

   ;; dired-mode
   '(dired-directory ((t (:inherit (font-lock-keyword-face)))))
   '(dired-flagged ((t (:inherit (diff-hl-delete)))))
   '(dired-symlink ((t (:foreground "#FD5FF1"))))

   ;; helm
   `(helm-header ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2
                      :background ,atom-one-dark-bg
                      :underline nil
                      :box (:line-width 6 :color ,atom-one-dark-bg)))))
   `(helm-source-header ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2
                             :background ,atom-one-dark-bg
                             :underline nil
                             :weight bold
                             :box (:line-width 6 :color ,atom-one-dark-bg)))))
   `(helm-selection ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(helm-selection-line ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(helm-visible-mark ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-bg :foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(helm-candidate-number ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1))))
   `(helm-separator ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg :foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(helm-M-x-key ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))
   `(helm-bookmark-addressbook ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))
   `(helm-bookmark-directory ((t (:foreground nil :background nil :inherit helm-ff-directory))))
   `(helm-bookmark-file ((t (:foreground nil :background nil :inherit helm-ff-file))))
   `(helm-bookmark-gnus ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(helm-bookmark-info ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(helm-bookmark-man ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(helm-bookmark-w3m ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(helm-match ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(helm-ff-directory ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan :background ,atom-one-dark-bg :weight bold))))
   `(helm-ff-file ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :background ,atom-one-dark-bg :weight normal))))
   `(helm-ff-executable ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green :background ,atom-one-dark-bg :weight normal))))
   `(helm-ff-invalid-symlink ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg :weight bold))))
   `(helm-ff-symlink ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg :weight bold))))
   `(helm-ff-prefix ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-bg :background ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :weight normal))))
   `(helm-buffer-not-saved ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(helm-buffer-process ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(helm-buffer-saved-out ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg))))
   `(helm-buffer-size ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(helm-buffer-directory ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(helm-grep-cmd-line ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))
   `(helm-grep-file ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg))))
   `(helm-grep-finish ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(helm-grep-lineno ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(helm-grep-finish ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(helm-grep-match ((t (:foreground nil :background nil :inherit helm-match))))

   ;; git-commit
   `(git-commit-comment-action  ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green :weight bold))))
   `(git-commit-comment-branch  ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue :weight bold))))
   `(git-commit-comment-heading ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :weight bold))))

   ;; js2-mode
   `(js2-function-call ((t (:inherit (font-lock-function-name-face)))))
   `(js2-function-param ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-1))))
   `(js2-jsdoc-tag ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(js2-jsdoc-type ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(js2-jsdoc-value((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(js2-object-property ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))

   ;; magit
   `(magit-section-highlight ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-hl))))
   `(magit-section-heading ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :weight bold))))
   `(magit-section-heading-selection ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :weight bold))))
   `(magit-diff-file-heading ((t (:weight bold))))
   `(magit-diff-file-heading-highlight ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray :weight bold))))
   `(magit-diff-file-heading-selection ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2 :background ,atom-one-dark-bg-hl :weight bold))))
   `(magit-diff-hunk-heading ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2 :background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(magit-diff-hunk-heading-highlight ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-1 :background ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))
   `(magit-diff-hunk-heading-selection ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple :background ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))
   `(magit-diff-context ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg))))
   `(magit-diff-context-highlight ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg))))
   `(magit-diffstat-added ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-diffstat-removed ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(magit-process-ok ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-process-ng ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(magit-log-author ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(magit-log-date ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(magit-log-graph ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-silver))))
   `(magit-sequence-pick ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(magit-sequence-stop ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-sequence-part ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))
   `(magit-sequence-head ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue))))
   `(magit-sequence-drop ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(magit-sequence-done ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(magit-sequence-onto ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(magit-bisect-good ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-bisect-skip ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))
   `(magit-bisect-bad ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(magit-blame-heading ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(magit-blame-hash ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(magit-blame-name ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(magit-blame-date ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))
   `(magit-blame-summary ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1 :foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(magit-dimmed ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(magit-hash ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(magit-tag  ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1 :weight bold))))
   `(magit-branch-remote  ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green :weight bold))))
   `(magit-branch-local   ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue :weight bold))))
   `(magit-branch-current ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue :weight bold :box t))))
   `(magit-head           ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue :weight bold))))
   `(magit-refname        ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg :foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :weight bold))))
   `(magit-refname-stash  ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg :foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :weight bold))))
   `(magit-refname-wip    ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg :foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :weight bold))))
   `(magit-signature-good      ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-signature-bad       ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(magit-signature-untrusted ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))
   `(magit-cherry-unmatched    ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))
   `(magit-cherry-equivalent   ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(magit-reflog-commit       ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-reflog-amend        ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(magit-reflog-merge        ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-reflog-checkout     ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue))))
   `(magit-reflog-reset        ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(magit-reflog-rebase       ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(magit-reflog-cherry-pick  ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(magit-reflog-remote       ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))
   `(magit-reflog-other        ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))

   ;; rainbow-delimiters
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-4-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-5-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-6-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-7-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-9-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-2))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-10-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-1))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-11-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-2))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-12-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))
   `(rainbow-delimiters-unmatched-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-black))))

   ;; rbenv
   `(rbenv-active-ruby-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))

   ;; smartparens
   `(sp-show-pair-mismatch-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1 :background ,atom-one-dark-gray :weight bold))))
   `(sp-show-pair-match-face ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray :weight bold))))

   ;; web-mode
   `(web-mode-symbol-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))

   ;; flx-ido
   `(flx-highlight-face ((t (:inherit (link) :weight bold))))

   ;; rpm-spec-mode
   `(rpm-spec-tag-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue))))
   `(rpm-spec-obsolete-tag-face ((t (:foreground "#FFFFFF" :background ,atom-one-dark-red-2))))
   `(rpm-spec-macro-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))
   `(rpm-spec-var-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1))))
   `(rpm-spec-doc-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple))))
   `(rpm-spec-dir-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan))))
   `(rpm-spec-package-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-2))))
   `(rpm-spec-ghost-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-2))))
   `(rpm-spec-section-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-2))))

   ;; term
   `(term-color-black ((t :foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-1)))
   `(term-color-blue ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-blue))))
   `(term-color-cyan ((t :foreground ,atom-one-dark-cyan)))
   `(term-color-green ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-green))))
   `(term-color-magenta ((t :foreground ,atom-one-dark-purple)))
   `(term-color-red ((t :foreground ,atom-one-dark-red-1)))
   `(term-color-white ((t :foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg)))
   `(term-color-yellow ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-orange-1))))

   ;; linum
   `(linum ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-gutter :background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
   ;; hlinum
   `(linum-highlight-face ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-accent :background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
   ))

(atom-one-dark-with-color-variables
  (custom-theme-set-variables
   'atom-one-dark
;;;;; fill-column-indicator
   `(fci-rule-color ,atom-one-dark-gray)
   ))

(defvar atom-one-dark-theme-force-faces-for-mode t
  "If t, atom-one-dark-theme will use Face Remapping to alter the theme faces for
the current buffer based on its mode in an attempt to mimick the Atom One Dark
Theme from Atom.io as best as possible.
The reason this is required is because some modes (html-mode, jyaml-mode, ...)
do not provide the necessary faces to do theming without conflicting with other
modes.
Current modes, and their faces, impacted by this variable:
* js2-mode: font-lock-constant-face, font-lock-doc-face, font-lock-variable-name-face
")

;; Many modes in Emacs do not define their own faces and instead use standard Emacs faces when it comes to theming.
;; That being said, to have a real "Atom One Dark Theme" for Emacs, we need to work around this so that these themes look
;; as much like "Atom One Dark Theme" as possible.  This means using per-buffer faces via "Face Remapping":
;;
;;   http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html
;;
;; Of course, this might be confusing to some when in one mode they see keywords highlighted in one face and in another
;; mode they see a different face.  That being said, you can set the `atom-one-dark-theme-force-faces-for-mode` variable to
;; `nil` to disable this feature.
(defun atom-one-dark-theme-change-faces-for-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (and (eq atom-one-dark-theme-force-faces-for-mode t)
       (cond
        ((member major-mode '(js2-mode))
         ;; atom-one-dark-orange-1
         (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-constant-face :foreground "#D19A66")
         (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-doc-face '(:inherit (font-lock-comment-face)))
         ;; atom-one-dark-mono-1
         (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-variable-name-face :foreground "#ABB2BF"))
        )))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'atom-one-dark-theme-change-faces-for-mode)

;;;###autoload
(and load-file-name
    (boundp 'custom-theme-load-path)
    (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path
                 (file-name-as-directory
                  (file-name-directory load-file-name))))
;; Automatically add this theme to the load path

(provide-theme 'atom-one-dark)

;; Local Variables:
;; no-byte-compile: t
;; End:
;;; atom-one-dark-theme.el ends here
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change [these lines](https://github.com/jonathanchu/atom-one-dark-theme/blob/master/atom-one-dark-theme.el#L84-L88).

```
 `(mode-line ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-black 
                  :foreground ,atom-one-dark-silver))))
 `(mode-line-buffer-id ((t (:weight bold))))
 `(mode-line-emphasis ((t (:weight bold))))
 `(mode-line-inactive ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
```

`:foreground` is the color of texts. `:background` is, well, background color. If you don't want any background use `:background nil`. If you want the borders use `:border t`. Note that if you specify anything for `mode-line-buffer-id` is will be used in both active and inactive buffers. But if you don't specify, say, `:border` it will inherit from `mode-line` in active buffers and `mode-line-inactive` in inactive buffers. If you don't like the [predefined](https://github.com/jonathanchu/atom-one-dark-theme/blob/master/atom-one-dark-theme.el#L18-L39) colors just use regular color names (e.g `:background "grey"`) or hexadecimal colors (`:background "#eeeeee"`).

These attributes are also available:

`:family`
`:width`
`:height`
`:weight`
`:slant`
`:underline`
`:overline`
`:strike-through`
`:box`
`:foreground`
`:background`
`:stipple`
`:inverse-video`
`:inherit`